# for loop to make new variables in r

Tags: r, loops

I want to create 9 new variables which are called bank1, bank2, through bank9. These will be the column names. The values will be a full column of 1 of bank1, 2 for bank2, and so on and so forth. Now I was reading on loops and I have a code that does the loop but do no know how to store these values. This is what I got so far. I want to add these columns to Subs dataframe.

```
set.seed(3)
Subs <- data.frame(value = rnorm(10, 0, 1))

for(i in 1:9){
Subs <- assign(paste("bank", i, sep = ""), i)    
}
```

Comment: remove the `Subs <- `. If you meant adding ROWNAMES then substitute the previous snippet with `rownames(Subs)[i] <-`.

Comment: @user2974951 the column names. This is my error~ new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Comment: Your data frame has 10 rows and 1 column, you cannot add columns or column names, not like this, by trying to put in 1 value. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I want 9 new columns called bank1, bank2 through bank9. all rows for bank1 = 1 and all rows for bank2 =2 and so on and so forth. all values of bank1 = 1 etc. Cheers!

Comment: `set.seed(3);
Subs <- data.frame(value = rnorm(10, 0, 1));
for (i in 1:10) Subs[[paste0("bank", i)]] <- i` ... `library("fortunes"); fortune(236)`

Comment: jogo answer is good for what I am doing. what is fortunes for?

Comment: `fortune(236)` is to comment your original code. ;-)